# How do I cope with a wisteria gone wild?

Tags: pruning, climbers

It is entirely my own fault and I have no excuse.

Having planted it, I have stood by and done nothing for three years except screw a trellis to the wall ... and then another trellis ... and then another, as the thing went out of control.

Belatedly, I checked out YouTube and discovered it is supposed to be heavily pruned  - and that, twice a year - to keep it under control and to make it flower.

Now, it is just a mass of leaves and tangled branches.

Can anyone suggest a way out of this mess ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed some siding done on the house and cut my wisteria down from sixteen feet tall to a three foot stub.  It regrew to twenty feet tall in a single season.  If it is a healthy vine you can be pretty hard cutting it back and it will be better for it.

Comment: Noted and appreciated. Thank you.